# Working with German Niederlassungserlaubnis in the Netherlands remotely?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, netherlands, work-permit

I got my *Niederlassungserlaubnis* (through Blue card) and now technically I should be able to work in EU countries (excluding Denmark, Ireland) without restriction.

I have a job offer from the Netherlands that offers remote work possibility. I don’t want to move physically to the Netherlands (Family, cost and etc) but one of the main reasons is that I am uncertain what is going to happen to my *Niederlassungserlaubnis* as a result, if I rent a small apartment and register myself in another EU country.

Will I lose my *Niederlassungserlaubnis* because I have two conflicting EU addresses in two different countries? I still want to pay taxes in Germany (where I live) and use my insurance in Germany and pay contributions to the statutory pension fund in Germany from the salary I earn in the Netherlands.

I prefer to avoid that because of double taxation complexity and perhaps other unknowns. I know it’s a complex question. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: No, a Blue Card or Permanent Residence Permits does not give you the right to work in European countries, only in the country that issued your residence permit.

Comment: Why would you be registering in another country? You can live in Germany and work remotely in another country without being registered there. The question is whether the Dutch employer will employ you with your visa status, and whether the Niederlassungserlaubnis has any requirements that you need to be employed by a German employer. *If* the Dutch employer will employ you remotely *and* this is permissible as per the Niederlassungserlaubnis, the worst that might happen is that you need to file your own taxes for "income from abroad" and pay into the Rentenkasse and Krankenkasse yourself.